# Will 2 OCZ Vertex 4 SSDs work on Asus G73SW?

Tags: laptop, ssd

Good day,

I've Googled this and I get contradictory answers on whether my laptop supports SATA3 or if it even can accept SSD drives at all. Some people say they installed an SSD drive but it runs at the normal speed of a standard hard drive...

It's an ASUS G73SW. It has 2 hard drive bays, and I'd like to add 2 SSDs in and (if it makes a big performance difference) RAID0 them.

I also tried calling Asus but couldn't get through at the time.

Anyone have any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is not important if your laptop supports SATA 3 or used the older SATA 2 standard. They are backward compatible and any SATA 3 device should work fine in both. (Albeit at SATA 2 speeds)

For the rest: SSD drives are not different from hard drives. Both speak SATA, both use the same connectors etc. etc. Basically if you can use a HDD then you should be able to use a SSD.

Answer (score 0):

They will work and will be much faster than the platter hard drives. you will want to try and find an Intel driver that supports TRIM on a RAID0.

Some reading material: http://forums.storagereview.com/index.php/topic/30589-intel-bringing-trim-support-to-raid0-with-rst-115-discussion/